# posting data resulting in error

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to do a very simple POST from an android application to a php script that will update a database. Unfortunately, this is giving me a debugger error (eclipse) on line 52. Below is the code:

```
package com.example.testhttppost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void updateDiscountTable(View view)
    {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/jsonpost.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shop", "ZARA"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("discount", "20%"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);    //Line 52

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

and the PHP script is:

```
<?php
    // PHP variable to store the host address
     $db_host  = "localhost";
     // PHP variable to store the username
     $db_uid  = "dsdsdsv_android";
     // PHP variable to store the password
     $db_pass = "test1234";
     // PHP variable to store the Database name  
     $db_name  = "dsdsdsv_android"; 
            // PHP variable to store the result of the PHP function 'mysql_connect()' which establishes the PHP & MySQL connection  
     $db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
     mysql_select_db($db_name);

     $shopId = $_POST['id'];
     $shopName = $_POST['shop'];
     $discount = $_POST['discount'];

     mysql_query("insert into discounts(id, shop, discount) values ($shopId, $shopName, $discount)");
//  mysql_query("insert into discounts(id, shop, discount)values(121, 'sadsdas','dasdasdsa')");

?>
```

The interface of the application is nothing but a button. This button is linked with the method above defined updateDiscountTable. Thanks and looking forward to replies.

Comment: 07-13 20:39:35.531: E/AndroidRuntime(12708):  at com.example.testhttppost.MainActivity.updateDiscountTable(MainActivity.java:52)

Comment: NeworkOnMainThreadException. Use an AsyncTask

Comment: Personally I am not sure if the code posting is correct because I copied it from online with little modifications. ANything spotted??

Comment: You mentioned that you want to update the database but you are using only insert. What if the data is already present for that key?

Comment: agree but when learning it is not. I am trying to see output of code snippet to understand its function. This is not production code

Answer (score 0):

You are performing networking operations on the main application thread probably. You need to move this to a background thread. You can use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You need to [Keep your app responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Comment: but why is it showing the line with response object as error line? And can that not be ignored for testing purposes? I know it affects smoothness but functionality?